# why doesnt this code print a full V pattern?

Tags: python, for-loop

I dont see why this isnt working. It should print a full V but it doesnt it stops printing at col 8

```
for row in range(5):
    for col in range(8):
        if row == col or row + col == 9:
            print("*",end='')
        else:
            print(' ',end='')
    print()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "it stops printing at col 8" Where the code says `for col in range(8):`, what do you think this means? How did you choose to use the number `8` here, instead of any other number? What effect do you expect this to have on the code? If you try changing this number, what is the effect on the output? Can you see a way to use this to solve the problem?

Comment: For future reference, please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and try to trace through the logic of your program carefully before posting. It is [expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592).

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide a big enough column number. 8 is exactly what you passed to the range of the second loop. However, your 'V' needs as many columns as two times the number of rows.

```
for row in range(5):
    for col in range(10):
        if row == col or row + col == 9:
            print("*",end='')
        else:
            print(' ',end='')
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

change col in range(8) to range(10) you will have full V. Because a full V need 10 column
This is the full code

```
for row in range(5):
    for col in range(10):
        if row == col or row + col == 9:
            print("*",end='')
        else:
            print(' ',end='')
    print()
```